# not able to create nested routes with okta react login

Tags: reactjs, okta

I am new to react and  am using okta react login.

```
function onAuthRequired({ history }) {
  history.push("/login");
}

function SecureApp() {
  return (
    <Security
      issuer="issuer name"
      client_id="client id name"
      redirect_uri={window.location.origin + "/callback"}
      onAuthRequired={onAuthRequired}
    >
      <div className="App">
        <SecureRoute path="/" exact={true} component={Dashboard} />
        <SecureRoute path="/logout" exact={true} component={Login} />
        <Route path="/login" render={() => <Login baseUrl={api.baseurl} />} />
        <Route path="/callback" component={ImplicitCallback} />
      </div>
    </Security>
  );
}
```

here In side dashboard component i am not able to create nested route

```
    `<h1>dashboard</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/projects`}>Projects</Link>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <Route path={`${match.path}/projects`} component={Projects} />`
```

**error**:
SecurityError: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'http://projects/' cannot be created in a document with origin 'http://localhost:3000' and URL 'http://localhost:3000/'.

Comment: Could you create a project with a similar scenario in CodeSandbox for example? With that, we could help you better :)

Comment: https://developer.okta.com/code/react/okta_react/ i just follwed these steps in the documentation .here inside secure route how to create another route as  nested route.thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create your route with /projects then simply add your path to Route

```
 <Route path='/projects' component={Projects} />
```

And you can access your route like

```
<Link to='/projects' >Projects</Link>
```

Comment: try to learn more about react router https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start

Comment: if you still have any problem then let me know

Comment: it is not loading anything .blank page is coming.

Comment: have you added your route in your main router ?

Comment: i want that component view to be render in dashboard component as a sub component.if i add in main router it is overriding the dashboard page and it wont be secure also.